# IE redirect warning with JavaScript void(); return false

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, void

I have the following markup for show/hide button that shows and hides 2 sections on my page with one onclick event

```
<a class="hideshow"     onclick="javascript:toggleSection('mytBodyID', 'spanID'); javascript:toggleSection('myspanID', 'spanID');" href="javascript:void();return false;">
        <span id="spanID">
          <%If resDisplay = "display:none" Then%>
            show<%Else%>
              hide<%End If%>
        </span>
```

The toggleSection does it's job but I do get "Are you sure you want to leave this page?" IE warning whenever clicking on the show/hide link. No mater if I click on "Leave this page" or "Stay on this page", I do not get redirected. It's just the warning dialog box that I do want to get rid off. I assume this is something about void() call in the href. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the javascript in your `href` and add a `#`. Your link will now stay on the current page.

```
<a class="hideshow" onclick="javascript:toggleSectionUpdateLink('pRouteControl1', 'pRouteControlLink'); javascript:toggleSectionUpdateLink('pRouteControl2', 'pRouteControlLink');" href="#">
    <span id="pRouteControlLink">
        <%If resDisplay = "display:none" Then%>
            show<%Else%>
            hide<%End If%>
    </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Wordked like a charm. Thanks!